# Google Drive thumbnailLinks returning 403 on localhost

Tags: google-drive-api, localhost, http-status-code-403

I am successfully getting a thumbnailLink from google Drive for the purpose of displaying it in the same app that gets this link. The thumbnailLink is successfully displayed when the app is running on a production server, or when copy and pasted in a browser, but not on localhost, where it returns a 403.

Typical thumbnailLink returned: [https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/p4OAiOaP0dBaE4JF…1vTCqNEUVdTH9CoCDAeAZB4D38cIvYpktGekW0IuBpRI=s220](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/p4OAiOaP0dBaE4JF%E2%80%A61vTCqNEUVdTH9CoCDAeAZB4D38cIvYpktGekW0IuBpRI=s220)

How can I manage to display these images by using the thumbnailLink on localhost please?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const App = () => {
    const [ googleAuth, setGoogleAuth ] = useState({})
  const [ thumbnailLink, setThumbnailLink ] = useState([])
    
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    
    const params = {
        apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
        client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest"],
        scope: SCOPES
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        window.gapi && window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
            window.gapi.client.init(params)
                .then(onInit)
        })
    }, [])

    const onInit = () => {
        setGoogleAuth(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance())
    }

    const signIn = () => {
        googleAuth.signIn()
            .then(response => console.log('Success: ', response))
            .catch(err => console.log("Error: ", err))
    }

  const getThumbnail = () => {
    gapi.client.drive.files.get({
            fileId: '1VFjfZlquVVUkHSmISKjH57UC0OaIQzVo',
      fields: 'thumbnailLink'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      setThumbnailLink(response.result.thumbnailLink)
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={signIn}>Sign In</button>
            <button onClick={getThumbnail}>getThumbnail</button>
            {thumbnailLink && <img src={thumbnailLink} />} // returns 403 on localhost
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: The thumbnail you posted seems to not be available to the public as it's returning a 403 error, this may be due to permissions on the file, you may as well check the thumbnail link description in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) as it states the following: `Only populated when the requesting app can access the file's content`

Comment: I should have known that the thumbnailLink is short-lived and that it would eventually return a 403 when used in a browser. A webViewLink however is permanent, and when this is fetched in the app, and used by the app as the 'src' attribute for an image, a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) warning returned when the app is running on localhost, but not when the app is running in production: the webLinkView just works fine. So, the app can access the file's content, it can use the thumbnailLink (or webViewLink) in production, but not on localhost. I am suspecting a CORS issue.

Answer (score 1):

> thumbnailLink string  A short-lived link to the file's thumbnail. Typically lasts on the order of hours. Only populated when the ***requesting app can access the file's content***. If the file isn't shared publicly, the URL returned in Files.thumbnailLink ***must be fetched using a credentialed request***.

Looks like you are not sending the get request with credentials....
And It could be a problem with the scope....for this I am not sure...

And you can also check this https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors?hl=en

this have almost all possible resolutions for error 403....

Comment: When I run this logic in production, thumbnailLinks work fine, without a credentialed request (I did not find documentation on how to do a credentialed request). Also, webViewLink, does not require a credentialed request, and if I use that as the 'src' attribute of the 'img' element, I still do not get it to work on loalhost, but it does work on production. Chrome's Network tab states 'Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin'. If I use either the thumbnailLink or the webViewLink directly in a browser, I get 'Referrer Policy: origin'. So my issue is most probably a CORS one.

Comment: I also went through the 'Resolve a 403 error' section of the page you provided: all of these errors are api related, and I am not getting a JSON object with the response as stated in this documentation; which makes me think it is indeed just a CORS issue. And an interesting detail, when using a webViewLink instead of a thumbnailLink, I do not get a 403, but a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB). To date I still cannot get these links to work on localhost.

Comment: yess!! I agree I tried to reproduce the error by myself (in react native)and yes the problem is there but I am getting 500 status code error with a html page with it......And webViewLink is working for me too......